# Does LightGBM cli support "feature_name" config?

Tags: lightgbm

I'm using libsvm as the input data format, and want to know how I could pass column name to LightGBM cli.

I found that LightGBM python API support a parameter feature_name, does cli version support the same field? I cannot find it through doc.

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html#lightgbm.train

Answer (score 1):

This question was cross-posted to the LightGBM issues board, https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/3731 and answered there.

Yes, feature names in the CLI are supported by using the `header` parameter, documented at https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#header. Add feature names as the first line in your data file and use that parameter to tell the LightGBM CLI to look in the header for feature names.